# I'm getting error while installing MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

While installing MongoDB in Windows 10, I'm facing this unexpected error. I had already install/uninstall setup many times and also disable my antivirus while installing this setup, still same issue.

Any suggestions?

[image: This is the error showing me while installing MongoDB]

Please see the image above.

Comment: It looks like you are not the administrator or the account you have logged as doesn't have administrator rights. Login in as administrator and try re-installing MongoDB

Comment: @hhharsha36 There is only one account in my OS I mean I am installing this from admin account.

Comment: Try run as administrator